# Quoting after pipe

Tags: r, tidyverse, quote, magrittr, rlang

I am building a function and would like to retrieve the variable name after a pipe (`%>%`). Is it possible?
When I use `enexpr`, it gives the dot sign ("`.`"). My expected answer would be "mpg", "cyl", etc...

```
> f <- function(x) enexpr(x)
> mtcars$mpg %>% f()
.
> mtcars %>% map(~f(.))
$mpg
.
$cyl
.
$disp
.
$hp
.
$drat
.
$wt
.
$qsec
.
$vs
.
$am
.
$gear
.
$carb
.
```

Comment: Aren't we just passing unnamed numeric vector by doing: `mtcars$mpg` ? How would you get the `mpg` out of it?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to retrieve just the symbol of the variable that is being altered in a pipe. In mpg case, i would like to retrieve "mpg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `imap`, you get the name in `.y` and the main variable in `.x` (or just `.`).

e.g.

```
c(N1='A',N2='B') %>% imap( ~ .y )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I would like to quote it and build a function around it.

Comment: well @dsz gave you the output you asked for, maybe you should elaborate your question to show how it doesn't answer. Do you need `x <- c(N1='A',N2='B') %>% imap( ~ as.symbol(.y) )` ?